# Write data in text file using node

Tags: node.js

I am new to node and file handling. below my code work perfectly

```
const data = 'Dummy data';
   fs.appendFile('./../log/TempLog.txt', data, function(error){
});
```

But when same code place inside the function which is in other module file is not written i tried it in many ways please check my code below

```
const fs = require("fs");
 function WriteData(data) {
    fs.appendFile('./../log/TempLog.txt', data, function(error){
   });
}
 module.exports.WriteData = WriteData;
```

Also the Writedata function called form index module as shown below

```
const writeLog = require('./public/writeLog');
server.on("connection", function (socket) {
    const decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');
 socket.on("data", function (d) {
       writeLog.WriteData(decoder.write(d));
    });

}
```

am i doing it wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you call that WriteData function ?

Comment: WriteData function is in index.js which is my main module and i dont want all code in that main file so i create separate module for file handeling.This WriteData function called on data event in socket

Comment: Can you update the code you require this file and the code you call this function in this ?

Comment: i updated my code

Comment: The code seem fine, can you make sure that `decoder.write(d)` return anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reviewing my own code i finally got the solution below :
The problem was with my path although the `writedata.js` module is in public folder but this will loaded into `index.js` as i imported into main module so i give path of text file referring to `index file`.